Compile issues with gz fortress custom plugin when trying to include <gz/sim.hh>
I'm trying to migrate a custom plugin from gazebo classic to gz fortress. I'm on Ubuntu 22 and using ros2 humble and have been able to follow the migration guide here https://gazebosim.org/docs/fortress/migrating_gazebo_classic_ros2_packages/ with no problems. I was able to launch the turtlebot sim as well as modify my robot's launch files to launch it in an empty world, etc.
However, after that I tried to follow the plugin migration guide here https://gazebosim.org/api/gazebo/6/migrationplugins.html
I have a simple file that does nothing more than try to #include <gz/sim.hh> but it gives fatal error: No such file or directory
I believe I've installed the necessary packages including
ros-humble-ros-gz-sim
libgz-sim6-dev
ignition-fortress

I've also verified that the file does exist at /usr/include/ignition/gazebo6/gz/sim.hh. I think the problem might be with my CMakeLists.txt file? Other than
find_package(ros_gz_bridge REQUIRED)
find_package(ros_gz_sim REQUIRED)

I wasn't sure what else to find_package(). I could hardcode the path in include_directories(/usr/include/ignition/gazebo6) but obviously that's not ideal and only resulted in different include errors.
Does anyone know of a tutorial/resource I could reference? I'm having a hard time finding one, I think maybe due to some links showing modern gazebo and some showing classic gazebo

It is not entirely clear to me why you'd want to include <gz/sim.hh> or what functionality exactly this file would provide.
If I look through the migration guide you refer to (https://gazebosim.org/api/gazebo/6/migrationplugins.html), I find no references to gz/sim.hh.
The files included in the example code are:
#include <gz/sim/Model.hh>
#include <gz/sim/Util.hh>
#include <gz/sim/System.hh>
#include <gz/plugin/Register.hh>

To my knowledge, only gz/sim/System.hh and gz/plugin/Register.hh are strictly necessary to implement a plugin. The former defines the System, ISystemConfigure, ISystemPreUpdate, ISystemUpdate and ISystemPostUpdate interfaces (see here), and the latter profides the functionality to load the system as a plugin.
For example code see the system plugin folder in the gz-sim repository. E.g. here is a simple header file.

Sorry I did try those includes from the migration guide but got 'fatal error no such file' and while I was playing around with different includes I accidentally copied over the wrong one when making this post. The example code in the system plugins folder was quite helpful though, thank you

I ended up having to modify my CMakeLists.txt file with several packages and also adding them to include_directories. I'm fairly certain this isn't the right way to do it, as it feels very manual, but it worked for me. I found the majority of these from the top-level CMakeLists.txt file of the gz-sim repo https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/blob/ign-gazebo6/CMakeLists.txt
# Setting this policy enables using the protobuf_MODULE_COMPATIBLE
# set command when cmake_minimum_required is less than 3.13
set(CMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMP0077 NEW)
# This option is needed to use the PROTOBUF_GENERATE_CPP
# in case protobuf is found with the CMake config files
# It needs to be set before any find_package(...) call
# as protobuf could be find transitively by any dependency
set(protobuf_MODULE_COMPATIBLE TRUE)

find_package(ros_gz_bridge REQUIRED)
find_package(ros_gz_sim REQUIRED)

ign_find_package(ignition-gazebo6 REQUIRED)
set(IGN_GAZEBO_VER ${ignition-gazebo6_VERSION_MAJOR})

ign_find_package(ignition-common4 REQUIRED)
set(IGN_COMMON_VER ${ignition-common4_VERSION_MAJOR})

ign_find_package(ignition-msgs8 REQUIRED)
set(IGN_MSGS_VER ${ignition-msgs8_VERSION_MAJOR})

ign_find_package(ignition-math6 REQUIRED)
set(IGN_MATH_VER ${ignition-math6_VERSION_MAJOR})

ign_find_package(ignition-utils1 REQUIRED)
set(IGN_UTILS_VER ${ignition-utils1_VERSION_MAJOR})

ign_find_package(ignition-transport11 REQUIRED)
set(IGN_TRANSPORT_VER ${ignition-transport11_VERSION_MAJOR})

ign_find_package(ignition-plugin1 REQUIRED)
set(IGN_PLUGIN_VER ${ignition-plugin1_VERSION_MAJOR})

ign_find_package(sdformat12 REQUIRED)
set(SDF_VER ${sdformat12_VERSION_MAJOR})

ign_find_package(IgnProtobuf REQUIRED COMPONENTS all PRETTY Protobuf)
set(Protobuf_IMPORT_DIRS ${ignition-msgs${IGN_MSGS_VER}_INCLUDE_DIRS})

include_directories(
  ${ignition-gazebo${IGN_GAZEBO_VER}_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${ignition-common${IGN_COMMON_VER}_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${ignition-msgs${IGN_MSGS_VER}_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${ignition-math${IGN_MATH_VER}_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${ignition-utils${IGN_UTILS_VER}_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${ignition-transport${IGN_TRANSPORT_VER}_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${ignition-plugin${IGN_PLUGIN_VER}_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${sdformat${SDF_VER}_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

